# Getting a numbers from a string with chars glued

Tags: c#, .net

I need to recover each number in a glued string

For example, from these strings:

```
string test = "number1+3"
string test1 = "number 1+4"
```

I want to recover (1 and 3) and (1 and 4)
How can I do this?

**CODE**

```
 string test= "number1+3";
 List<int> res; 

 string[] digits= Regex.Split(test, @"\D+");
 foreach (string value in digits)
 {
     int number;
     if (int.TryParse(value, out number))
     {
         res.Add(number)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Non-regex would need to iterate through each char and check if it's numeric

Comment: Mmmm.... let me try... Thanks @vc74

Comment: are all your strings in the formats specified above?

Comment: yep, @RuiJarimba

Comment: thanks @vc74, my mistake

Comment: @Matt not really, check my answer. In this particular case there's no need for regular expressions

Comment: @RuiJarimba `Split` iterates through the string, and I'm pretty sure `Select` will too

Comment: @Matt internally yes, but you don't need to do it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work

```
string pattern = @"\d+";
string test = "number1+3";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(test, pattern))
   Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", 
                     match.Value, match.Index);
```

Note that if you intend to use it multiple times, it's better, for performance reasons, to create a Regex instance than using this static method.

```
var res = new List<int>();

var regex = new Regex(@"\d+");

void addMatches(string text) {
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
    {
        int number = int.Parse(match.Value);
        res.Add(number);
    }
}

string test = "number1+3";
addMatches(test);

string test1 = "number 1+4";
addMatches(test1);
```

[MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_System_String_).

[Fiddle 1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C1AQSm)

[Fiddle 2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yKIysb)

Comment: Thanks so much for your efford @vc74

Comment: Please, rate my question as well if you think could be useful for the comunity :)

Answer (score 1):

This calls for a regular expression:

```
(\d+)\+(\d+)
```

[Test it](https://regex101.com/r/IIS39w/2)

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d+)\+(\d+)");

string first = m.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
string second = m.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to regular expressions:

```
string test = "number 1+4";

int[] numbers = test.Replace("number", string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    .Trim()
                    .Split("+", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
                    .ToArray();
```